# Can't install node-inspector in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nodejs, javascript, npm

When trying to install node-inspector with:

```
sudo npm install -g node-inspector
```

I had the following problem:

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/debug/v0.7.3/node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-debug@0.7.3 and node@6.1.0 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

Am i missing something?

The file that it tries to download does not exist...why does he even try it?

Can i install it manually?

Comment: could someone please create the tag node-inspector?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I fixed it by changing the grunt-node-inspector version in my package.json file to:
"grunt-node-inspector": ">=0.2.0",

After that just ran npm update and it worked.

Comment: Great! Worked for me on Centos 6.6. I was really stuck!...

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about what caused my problem, but i found a workaround based on an article [here](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/wiki/Getting-Started---from-scratch).

```
git clone http://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector.git
cd node-inspector
npm install -g
```

and it works...